# How hadoop YARN memory and core works?

Tags: hadoop, frameworks, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Before, I have read about hadoop YARN memory and core parameters that set on a cluseter. But, I still don't know clearly about that parameter. And also about the container. That on 1 node only has 1 container or more ? And on 1 cluster only have 1 Application Master or more?

Help me to know about container, application master, memory, and core works on YARN,

Thanks All.....

Answer (score 0):

[image: YARN Architecture]

The above diagram is from [apache YARN web site](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) . It gives a clear explanation about the inner details and functionality.

We set the parameters for YARN in yarn-site.xml in /conf .

property yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb can be used to set maximum amount of RAM that can be used by YARN on a node .

```
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>4096</value>
```

property yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb can be used to set minimum amount of memory for a container . For example if we have 16 GB memory and the yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb is 4GB . So we have 12 GB remaining and minimum of 2GB is allocated for each container thus we can have atmost 6 containers.

```
<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
<value>2048</value>
```

From the architecture you can clearly see that we will have more than one app master.